# How to implement RunAs in spring security acl

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, runas, spring-security-acl

I want to get a user to RunAs another role (that's an admin role: ROLE_USER_ADMIN) to change the privileges in an object owned by another user.

1. Create a Role with an authority 'ROLE_RUN_AS_USERADMIN'
2. enable RunAs in config.groovy

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.useRunAs = true`

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.runAs.key = '*****'`

3. give the generated role the authority to change Acl details

`grails.plugin.springsecurity.acl.authority.changeAclDetails = 'ROLE_RUN_AS_USERADMIN'`

4. Annotate the service method that accepts an invitation and sets the domain object privileges to allow access

`@PreAuthorize(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_RUN_AS_USERADMIN']) //run as ROLE_USER and ROLE_RUN_AS_INVITED_USER`

but I still get an error when an access control entry is to be added to the domain object's acl:

Unable to locate a matching ACE for passed permissions and SID